# Workaround for "Firefox: Event pages are not currently supported."

Tags: javascript, events, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to make a temporary extension preform cleanup upon being disabled or uninstalled.

heres the manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "nothing",
  "version": "0.9",
  "description": "empty",
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and this is background.js:

```
function messageContentScript() {
    console.log("Suspending Extension");
}

browser.runtime.onSuspend.addListener(messageContentScript);
```

After running it I get the following error on the last line of the script:

`TypeError: browser.runtime.onSuspend is undefined`

after trying to find a solution to the issue, I found a suggestion somewhere to change the manifest.json by adding a line `"persistent": false` in the background object, after doing this however, I get an error after simply reloading the extension in about:debugging. The error is as follows:

`Reading manifest: Error processing background.persistent: Event pages are not currently supported. This will run as a persistent background page.`
And `browser.runtime.onSuspend` is still undefined. Is my browser version (Firefox-ESR 68) simply unable to perform an onSuspend catch? Is there a workaround or not?

Comment: What are you really looking for here? Firefox doesn't support Event Pages, as is indicated [in the Browser Compatibility section of the `background` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/background#Browser_compatibility). Even if it did, `runtime.onSuspend` is fired when the Event Page is being suspended, not when the extension is being disabled/uninstalled. I'm not sure what you're looking for a workaround for.

Comment: @Makyen i was trying to find any way for my extension to perform some sort of cleanup immediately upon being disabled, but obviously I got quite a few things wrong while trying to ask my question